# How can i solve the following problem with pip?[Could not install packages due to an OSError]

Tags: python, pip, package, oserror

My virtual environment is accidentally not working. i found out this message when i tried to add new package to my virtual environment My problem is as following:
I've run this command.[`$ pip install <package_name>`]
But i met an error message.

`ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: Missing dependencies for SOCKS support.`

How can i fix the error? I need detailed information.

What did I try?

1. upgrade my pip version.
2. create new VENV(for python project).

How can i fix the error? pls, I need detailed information.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHaHt.jpg

Comment: does installing pysocks using pip install pysocks solves your problem?

Comment: _Thanks_, I tried to do so but **pip install** is not working for installing any package

Answer (score 1):

Try writing "pip3 install <package_name>"

Sometimes depending on what compiler or OS you are using there could be differences in installing packages. I had the same problem a while ago and writing "pip3" instead of just "pip" fixed the problem for me.

However, from the error code you're getting, that may not be the case. I assume you are on ubuntu so I would suggest running

```
$ env | grep -i proxy
```

then

`$ unset socks_proxy`

Comment: Thanks, _@London_. It seems like special case. I am windows user. Additionally, Python version is 3.11.2 , pip version is 22.3.1.